# Capturar un evento antes que ocurra con Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

La consulta concreta es ¿hay alguna manera de capturar el evento
antes que se efectivice?, o ¿tiene esto otra solución?.-
En apariencia funciona, lo que ocurre es que cuando se ejecuta
la excepción el IDE se queda como en un bucle infinito y no se deja
cerrar.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from functools import partial
import funciones

def rehacer(text, temp, event):
    try:
        text.edit_undo()
    except:
        text.insert(tk.INSERT, temp)

    return


def main():

    root = tk.Tk()

    text = tk.Text(root,width = 55,height = 10, undo=True)
    text.pack()

    temp = """ La inteligencia no se mide por el número
    de palabras que sabes pronunciar,
    sino por aquellas que no dices para no lastimar!!!
    """

    text.insert(tk.INSERT, temp)

    root.bind('<Control-z>', partial(rehacer, text, temp))
    
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: A mi no me ocurre lo mismo. Estás seguro de que no solucionaste el error mientras creabas el ejemplo de código que publicas?

Comment: Hola Dante.
Si, me sigue ocurriendo lo mismo, de cualquier manera ya 
encontré como solucionarlo.-